# How to pass associative array into function argument in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Can I pass an associative array name into function argument in PHP? I have the following array and I want to display all the movies under "comedy". For example, I want `filmsInCategory("comedy")` to return all the films in the comedy category.

```
$film = array(
  "comedy" => array(
    0 => "Pink Panther",
    1 => "john English",
    2 => "See no evil hear no evil"
  ),

  "action" => array (
    0 => "Die Hard",
    1 => "Expendables"
  ),

  "epic" => array (
    0 => "The Lord of the rings"
  ),

  "Romance" => array(
    0 => "Romeo and Juliet"
  )
);

//print_r($film);

$category;

function filmsInCategory($category) {
  echo $film[$category];
}

filmsInCategory("comedy");

foreach ($film as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . " = " . $value . "<br>";
  echo "Should output: " . $film["comedy"];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My variable was out of scope. I have placed it inside the function instead

```
function filmsInCategory($category) {
  $film = array(
    "comedy" => array(
      0 => "Pink Panther",
      1 => "john English",
      2 => "See no evil hear no evil"
    ),

    "action" => array (
      0 => "Die Hard",
      1 => "Expendables"
    ),

    "epic" => array (
      0 => "The Lord of the rings"
    ),

    "Romance" => array(
      0 => "Romeo and Juliet"
    )
  );
  // print_r($film);


  if ( array_key_exists($category, $film) ) {
    echo $category . " exists" . "<br>";

    foreach ($film[$category] as $key => $value) {
      echo $value . "<br>";
    }
  }
}

filmsInCategory("action");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```php
foreach ($film as $key => $value) {
    //$key here is the string "comedy" / $value here is the inner array
    filmsInCategory($key);
}
```

Comment: ^ it doesn't print out the values for all the categories